# How to add new field in My Account page using Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6

I want to add new field in My Account page, say check box for subscription, how can I do that ?

If there is a new field added in user profile, How can set its value on user's successful registration ? that is , one time setting DB value for that field .... Please suggest the way to do this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the profile module that is shipped with Drupal? It enables you to customize the Drupal user account page. If that is not enough, there are several profile modules that brings addition features.

Comment: I have seen that from admin section but didn't got solution also "If there is a new field added in user profile, How can I set its value on user's successful registration ? that is , one time setting DB value for that field .... Please suggest the way to do this ..."

Comment: @dev: If you use the profile module, the module will create a form field for it on registration by default that the user can fill in and which will be stored to the database.